# How do I make a Github pre-receive hook quickly read-in a checked-in/committed file for validation?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Here is the use-case:

I have a Github pre-receive hook, that is supposed to validate a value X by verifying if it exists in a committed file abc.txt. Since a hook in Github has a timeout of only 5 seconds, I want this hook to quickly open or read in this file and if the value exists, it will pass, if not then it will fail. Is there is Git command I can run with-in this script hook can access this file from its repo. Git clone is an option but would be tedious to run inside a pre-receive hook. I also tried git ls-remote but is only lists references and not actual content of file.

Comment: `pre-receive` should be able to access the pushed metadata. Try `git cat-file -p ${pushed_ref}:abc.txt | grep -e "X"`. `pushed_ref` can be read from stdin.

Comment: Hello, this may not work because the abc.txt is in another repo(not the one where the code is being pushed). Below is a more illustrated scenario:

**Repo A:**
- abc.txt (already checked-in and is on master)

**Repo B**
- myfile.doc
- Once it is pushed to master, the pre-receive hook should fire and access the "abc.txt" in repo A above to validate a value and will pass or fail the push.

Comment: Then try `git archive --remote=${url_to_RepoA} ${revision_of_RepoA} abc.txt | grep -e "X"`.